# ASP.NET MVC - The property or indexer cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please why am I having this error in the repository

> Error 18  The property or indexer 'BPP.CCSP.Admin.Infrastructure.STATES.COUNTRY_ID' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor

**Model**

```
    public int STATE_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> COUNTRY_ID { internal get; set; }
    public string STATE_NAME { get; set; }
```

**Repository**

```
    public class AdminManager : IAdminManager
{
    private readonly IRepository<STATES> _statesRepository;

    public AdminManager(IRepository<PRB> prbsRepository, IRepository<OPTIONS> optionRepository, IRepository<COUNTRIES> countriesRepository, IRepository<STATES> statesRepository, IRepository<CITIES> citiesRepository)
    {
        _statesRepository = statesRepository;
    }


    public SelectList stateList()
    {
        var countryId = _statesRepository.FindAll().Where(c => c.COUNTRY_ID == 1);
        var listStates = countryId.Select(c => new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem { Value = c.COUNTRY_ID.ToString(), Text = c.STATE_NAME }).OrderBy(c => c.Text).ToList();
        var listCount = new SelectList(listStates, "value", "text");
        return listCount;
    }
}
```

Please how do I resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
public Nullable<int> COUNTRY_ID { internal get; set; }
```

to

```
public Nullable<int> COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
```

Note that internal is for assembly scope. Your repository is (i'm guessing) in a different project than where your model is defined. A different project will create a different assembly so then the `internal get` will not allow the repo to access this property.